# sp.contract from hash key

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

In the test, I am trying to replace the admin with a fixed account.
But I cannot find what t should be.

*admin = sp.contract( t,"tz1dQXqXZ3Y5sgYwU9Aq9xRJPxEZNUwyE6ht", entry_point = "")

alice = sp.test_account("Alice")

bob   = sp.test_account("Robert")*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You want to do something like:**

```
import smartpy as sp

class Sample(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        self.init(**kargs)

    @sp.entry_point
    def ep(self):
        c = sp.contract(sp.TUnit, sp.address("tz1dQXqXZ3Y5sgYwU9Aq9xRJPxEZNUwyE6ht"))
        sp.transfer(sp.unit, sp.tez(10), c.open_some())

@sp.add_test(name = "Sample")
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    c1 = Sample()
    c1.set_initial_balance(sp.tez(1000000))
    scenario += c1
    c1.ep()
```

Comment: thank you so much again! Much appreciated!